# Handling a large-ish binary file, streaming to storage

Tags: java, android, odata4j

I am using Odata4j and my entity has one `Data` field which is a binary file. When viewing through a browser it shows as a Base64 string.

How can I get this file onto my Android device?

I have tried the following to get a `byte[]`...

```
String stringData = entity.getProperty("Data").getValue().toString();
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(stringData);
```

But this is just giving me a small array of about 7 bytes. However, when I debug I can see the `entity` data has a large binary value.

I also have an issue with a second file which is producing an "out of memory" exception, ideally I would like to be able to download this file straight to the device's storage as a stream/buffer, is this possible?

To be clear, the question is: How to stream this data straight onto the device's storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem without using OData. There is a URL available that will return just the binary data. So with this URL I can use other Java classes to stream the data directly to disk.

So with this URL:

> www.example.com/OData.svc/File/Data/$value

(which returns just the binary data)

We can create a URL connection and download it:

```
URL url = new URL(webPage);
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

File file = new File(dir, fileName);//need to create a file based on your storage paths

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int i = 0;
while ((i = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, i);
}

out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I surmise that `entity.getProperty("Data").getValue()` is actually returning a `byte[]` or `char[]`.  When you call `toString()` on an array (or in fact, any type that doesn't override `toString()`, you will get a short string composed of the object's type name and identity hashcode.  For a `byte[]` or `char[]` that could be 7 characters long.

I suggest you print out `entity.getProperty("Data").getValue().getClass()` to confirm the actual type.

Comment: Yes this is correct, it turns out it `getValue()` is already a byte[]. But I am still unable to save this to storage (although that itself is a different problem) However, I would like to stream the binary data straight to disk if possible using OData4j

Comment: @musefan - I can't help you with those questions.  I'm not a odata4j user / expert.